# jQuery show some content on radio select

Tags: jquery

I have 2 radio button (i.e., <input type="radio">) with values "yes","no"

Now, I need to show a 2 other fields when someone selects "yes"

I understand that I need to place them in <div>, but when someone selects "yes", then div should show, with some highlight

I need to achieve these 2 things (that I guess): showing up the div and highlighting it for some time (for user attention).

```
<input type="radio" id="dl" value="YES" />Yes
<input type="radio" id="dl" value="NO" checked />No

<div id="dlyes"><label>Number</label><input type="text" id="dlno" /></div>
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution uses both jQuery and jQueryUI...

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/gBedF/

Basically I assign a function to the change event of the radio button group. This tests if the radio button is yes or no (based on values).

If yes, we fade in the hidden div and fade out the background color (jQueryUI) after a delay of 500 milliseconds.

If the value of the radio button is no, we reset the background color and hide the div.

**HTML:** (note I have given both input elements the same 'name' attribute so that they are in a group.)

```
<input type="radio" id="dl" value="YES" name="yesno" />Yes
<input type="radio" id="dl" value="NO" name="yesno" checked />No
<div id="dlyes"><label>Number</label><input type="text" id="dlno" /></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#dlyes {    
   display:none;
   background-color:#efefef;
   width:400px;
   height:400px;
   margin-top:20px;           
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('input[name|="yesno"]').change(function() {
    if($(this).val()=='YES') {
        $('#dlyes').fadeIn(0, function() {
             $(this).delay(500).animate( { backgroundColor: "white" }, 1000);   
        });
    } else {
        $('#dlyes').css('background-color', '#efefef');
        $('#dlyes').fadeOut(0);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
var div = $("#dlyes");  
$("input:radio").click(funciton(){  
    var radioVal = this.value;  
    if(radioVal === "YES"){  
       div.show();  
       div.css({border: "solid 1px red"});  
       setTimeout(function(){div.css({border: "none"});}, 5000);  
    }
    else {
       div.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/T9f8F/

There are some problems with your HTML, first you will need to give each of your radio buttons the same `name` attribute. Also you have duplicate `id` attributes for both radios which must be changed or removed. In addition there is not need to capitalise the radio button values:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="myradios" value="yes"> Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="myradios" value="no" checked /> No</label>

<div id="dlyes">
    <label>Number</label><input type="text" id="dlno" />
</div>
```

Now the HTML is valid, we can look out for changes in the values of either radio button. It is important to remember that both radio buttons change when you select one, so you must check within the binding to the `change` event that `this.checked` is true to disregard the deselected radio button.

```
var $div = $('#dlyes');
// Hide the div using jQuery rather than CSS, as if JavaScirpt is disabled
// the user should still be able to access the inputs.
$div.hide();

$('input:radio[name="myradios"]').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        if (this.value == 'yes') {
            $div.show()
                .css('background-color', '#FFD700')
                .animate({'background-color': 'transparent'}, 1000);
        } else {
            $div.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

In order to slowly removed the highlight colour of the div, I have used the [jQuery color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) which is necessary for the `animate({backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 2000)` line.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/T9f8F/

Comment: I am only able to see that you have loaded jQuery library in jsfiddle, there is no library as "jQuery color plugin". Please help me understand why I can't see "jQuery color plugin"

Comment: @I-M-JM The jQuery-color plugin file is available [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/raw/master/jquery.color.js) . Just save the file and include it in the same way after you include your jQuery file.